Sum the value of a row in the same column only if it is higher than the previous value on PowerBI
I'm having an issue trying to sum values only if the prior value is lower than the next value.
These are done on an hourly basis
What I am getting by manually calculating the sum is at the bottom of these tables.
How would you go about this on DAX?



g1
g2




3
34


26
13


3
22


4
8


14
6


6
9


9
9


28
11


20
24



3


TOTAL 168
TOTAL 173



I tried doing this in excel by creating an array but I can't figure it out

It is not very clear what is the sum you want to do ?
Could you show the full calculus you do ?

could you pls provide the sample data(not calculated) and the expected output?
